# Dependency sorter for TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have problems with dependencies in `TypeScript`. How to sort them to make everything work? Are there any tools for that?

The problem looks like this... I have 2 modules:

```
module Module1 {
   export class A {
   }

   export class B {
   }
}

module Module2 {
   export class C {
   }

   export class D {
   }
}
```

`Module1` uses classes from `Module2` and `Module2` uses classes from `Module1`. So it's a kind of cycle here (on modules). Now when I compile it into `JavaScript` I get an error:

`Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Module2' is undefined`

It happens, because `Module2` `JS` reference should be included over `Module1`. How to solve the problem, when I have such cycles? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a grunt plugin specifically for this purpose : https://github.com/basarat/grunt-ts#javascript-generation-and-ordering

Also check out the video tutorial : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-6vT7xgE4Y&hd=1

Answer (score 2):

In Object Oriented Programming it helps to have dependencies flowing in a single direction. Having Module1 depending on Module2 and also Module2 depending on Module1 will cause problems even in languages that allow circular dependencies.

You should be able to solve the problem by having a Module3 that depends on both Module1 and Module2 - with no dependencies on Module3. In the example, I have assumed that B depends on C and D depends on A:

```
module Module1 {
   export class A {
   }
}

module Module2 {
   export class C {
   }
}

module Module3 {
   export class B {
   }

   export class D {
   }
}
```

Another solution may be to accept that if these two modules have this many dependencies - they should probably just be a single module.

```
module Module1 {
   export class A {
   }

   export class B {
   }

   export class C {
   }

   export class D {
   }
}
```