# Typescript declaration order triggers runtime error

Tags: typescript

Searching for a problem I have, I found claims that [the declaration order of classes doesn't matter in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387351/forward-declaration-in-typescript), and that 'forward declarations' are not necessary.

In a project I am reviewing right now, this claim doesn't seem to hold up. I broke the issue  down into a simple reproducible example, where even though the compiler doesn't complain, we fail at runtime:

```
$ cat bug.ts
class A extends B {
    constructor(public id:number) {
        super(id);
        console.log("A():" + id);
    }
}

class B {
    constructor(public id:number) {
        console.log("B():" + id);
    }
}

var a = new A(12);

$ tsc  bug.ts
$ node  bug.js

/home/ttsiod/work/a/bug.js:4
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at __extends (/home/ttsiod/work/a/bug.js:4:21)
    at /home/ttsiod/work/a/bug.js:8:5
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ttsiod/work/a/bug.js:15:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

Either I am missing a keyword I don't know about, or the claim of "declaration order is not  important" is not as generic as one would think.

Answer (score 3):

I matters for inheritance. It doesn't matter as long as it is **defined** *before* it is used, which is the case in the link you mentioned.

For inheritance B must be defined before A, so that A can copy over members from the prototype of B.

Also there is a distinction between "declaration" (where order *never* matters) and "definition" where order almost always matters except for cases like hoisting http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Comment: Isn't it fair to argue that if it necessary for inheritance, then the compiler should not allow this kind of code to pass? Isn't this, arguably, a compiler bug?

Comment: @ttsiodras further elaborated difference between *declaration* and *definition* It is the nature of JavaScript and the fact that the order in which you choose to load the generated JavaScript might be completely up to you which makes it difficult to enforce this as it will only work in specific scenarios

Comment: This is interesting, because TypeScript is clever enough to figure this out if it split across several files - it will change the order in the combined output when using the `--out` flag.

Comment: @SteveFenton no it will not, remove any `///reference` and compile using `tsc a.ts b.ts --out out.js` a will come out on top every time irrespective of contents. Basically typescript never does any *semantic* ordering, only respects your order via either `///reference` or order of files passed to `tsc`

Comment: Yes - you are right - it is actually the ordering in my references file that is dictating the ordering (I wrote my biggest TypeScript project when reference comments were mandatory - so I have a single `references.ts` file that handles them all.)